# Calculate Every n record SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
oDateTime                oValue
------------------------------------
2017-09:30 23:00:00      8
2017-09-30 23:15:00      7
2017-09-30 23:30:00      7
2017-09-30 23:45:00      7
2017-10-01 00:00:00      6
2017-10-01 00:15:00      5
2017-10-01 00:30:00      8
2017-10-01 00:45:00      7
2017-10-01 01:00:00      6
2017-10-01 01:15:00      9
2017-10-01 01:30:00      5
2017-10-01 01:45:00      6
2017-10-01 02:00:00      7
```

The table will have one record every 15 minutes. I want to `SUM` or `Average` those records every 15 minutes.
So, the result should be:

```
oDateTime                Sum_Value      Avg_Value
---------------------------------------------------
2017-10-01 00:00:00      35             7
2017-10-01 01:00:00      32             6.4
2017-10-01 02:00:00      33             6.6
```

the `SUM` for `2017-10-01 00:00:00` is taken from 5 records before it and so on.
does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want overlapping sums?

Comment: your double counting, surely you only want the previous 4. seems you want the previous 5 inclusive of itself. ie the previous 4 and itself. otherise how do you get 35 for 2017-10-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method in SQL Server 2008:

```
select t.oDateTime, tt.sum_value, tt.avg_value
from (select oDateTime
      from t
      where datepart(minute, oDateTime) = 0
     ) t outer apply
     (select sum(oValue) as sum_value, avg(oValue) as avg_Value
      from (select top 5 t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.oDateTime <= t.oDateTime
            order by t2.oDateTime desc
           ) tt
     ) tt;
```

In more recent versions of SQL Server, you can use window functions for this purpose.

Comment: this is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Just join the table to itself, and group by the master timestamp

This below is easily adjustable, to include how many minutes back you want. Handles change in frequency, i.e. doesn't assume 5 rows wanted, so if the data came in in 5 minutes intervals this is handled.

```
select cast('2017-09-30 23:00:00' as datetime) t,8  o
into #a
union all
select '2017-09-30 23:15:00',7 union all
select '2017-09-30 23:30:00',7 union all
select '2017-09-30 23:45:00',7 union all
select '2017-10-01 00:00:00',6 union all
select '2017-10-01 00:15:00',5 union all
select '2017-10-01 00:30:00',8 union all
select '2017-10-01 00:45:00',7 union all
select '2017-10-01 01:00:00',6 union all
select '2017-10-01 01:15:00',9 union all
select '2017-10-01 01:30:00',5 union all
select '2017-10-01 01:45:00',6 union all
select '2017-10-01 02:00:00',7 

select x.t,sum(x2.o),avg(cast(x2.o as float))
from   #a x, #a x2
where  x2.t between dateadd(mi,-60,x.t) and x.t 
group by x.t
```